# To find all lines in DataFrame by substring information

Tags: python, string, dataframe, select, search

I have a `dataframe` with number of columns and hundreds lines.

What would be the simple and best performance way to find all lines in `DataFrame` where cell in columns `my_columns` has a substring : `abc`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Its required here to show what you've tried in order to seek assistance, like a code sample. See more here [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try :

```
df[df['my_columns'].str.contains('abc')]
```

Comment: What if I need any UPPER or lower case strings? As example, we have 'vvAbCvv' in the cell of DataFrame?

Comment: @OcMaRUS, try contains('abc', case=False)

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Check the best answer here: [How to select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)
, it's all explained

```
print(df.loc[df['my_column'] == 'abc'])
```

Comment: Thanks, but 'abc' is a substing. cell can be "xxxabcyyy"

Comment: So than check out @Subasri sridhar answer :)